# Stateless component as a function or a const

Tags: reactjs

I'm aware of the benefits, of making a component stateless. What I'm not aware of is - what's the difference between making the component as a const or a function. I'm a bit confused, because I've seen several examples, using both.

```
function MyComponent(props) {
  return(
    <div>Hello world</div>
  )
}
```

vs.

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  return(
    <div>Hello world</div>
  )
}
```

Would be great with an explanation what to choose correctly

Comment: 1st one is a normal JavaScript function and the second one is arrow function. Arrow functions are helpful when you want to access this context inside function as arrow functions don’t need manual binding. But when it comes to components it’s up to you to choose

Comment: Sooo, when to use which one?

Comment: There is no difference in this case.

Comment: Please check this, it answers your question perfectly [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch)

Comment: Check this also https://medium.freecodecamp.org/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26

Comment: Also, it's not stateless vs stateful anymore. Functional components can be stateful (as of 16.7) and class components can be stateless.

Answer (score 0):

In this case for a stateless component definition there's no difference, you can do it either way, there's no right or wrong... however in my opinion is becoming more standard to define the components with arrow function, it probably looks more elegant as well.

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  return(
   <div>Hello world</div>
  )
}
```